# When I delete something in Android Studio and commit my changes to SVN, the file does not get marked for deletion on SVN.. why?

Tags: svn, android-studio

This is really frustrating.  Every time I try to delete files in Android Studio and commit my changes to SVN, the deletions don't carry over.  When other devs update to the latest revision, the files I deleted do not get deleted on their working copies.  Why is this?

I delete the file by simply right-clicking it in the project tree.  When I commit, I commit the entire project from the project root in the tree.  Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Because you have to `svn delete` to remove the file from version control before you commit.

Answer (score 13):

By default, Android Studio doesn't mark local actions as repo actions.

To change the setting so that local deletes are instantly marked as a repo deletes, go to Preferences -> Version Control -> Confirmation -> Remove silently (under 'When files are deleted').

Comment: I have set this but it seems it does not work. Please suggest me any other workaround.

Comment: As a workaround you can open the context menu ("right-click") of the file using project view and navigate to Git -> Add or Git-> Delete

Comment: Actually I need the solution fr SVN(Subversion) and you have suggested for Git. So, it is not working for me Thanks.

Comment: Ah, yes. Sorry about that, I imagine there would be something similar for SVN, but I do not know since have not used SVN in any project for at least 5+ years. Good luck!